# Filtering record from django model using a tuple

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I have a django model such as this

```
id   task_id                                status      content_type        content_encoding   result       date_done                                   meta                      task_args          
1    "9bb8b186-da5d-43b2-8fca-1496474b1cc9" "SUCCESS"   "application/json"  "utf-8"            """done"""   "2020-09-23 14:15:03.064283+05:30"          "{""children"": []}"       "('test_user', 1, ['test'], 'id_001')"
```

The `task_args` field in the model is a `text field`. How do I filter the model based on this data? Specifically I want the `task_id` where `task_args` is `('test_user', 1, ['test'], 'id_001')`

**This is my code so far**

```
user = request.user.username
num = 1
parsed_data = eval("['test']")
id = "id_001"

print(type(parsed_data))

args = f"{(user,num,parsed_data,id)}"
print(args)

task_id = list(TaskResult.objects.filter(task_args=args).values('task_id'))
```

> Right now this code outputs an empty list

Not sure what I am doing wrong.

Is this because I am passing the `tuple` as a `string`?

I am passing this as a `string` because the `task_args` field is a text field. I also tried passing this as a `tuple`. Even that results in an `empty list`.

Comment: what is the response of `print(args)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seems like a typo somewhere in your code. I did a similar test and got succeeded.

```
In [33]: Foo.objects.create(task_args="('test_user', 1, ['test'], 'id_001')")
Out[33]: <Foo: Foo object (4)>

In [34]: Foo.objects.all()
Out[34]: <QuerySet [<Foo: Foo object (4)>]>

In [35]: tuple_data = ('test_user',1,["test"],"id_001") # create a tuple

In [36]: str_tuple_data = str(tuple_data) # convert to a string

In [37]: str_tuple_data
Out[37]: "('test_user', 1, ['test'], 'id_001')"

In [38]: Foo.objects.filter(task_args=str_tuple_data)
Out[38]: <QuerySet [<Foo: Foo object (4)>]>

In [39]: Foo.objects.filter(task_args=str_tuple_data).values()
Out[39]: <QuerySet [{'id': 4, 'task_args': "('test_user', 1, ['test'], 'id_001')"}]>
```

Comment: The mistake I was making was passing different data to the model. An unwanted bug. This works now. Thanks a lot